# How can I propose and recieve ideas of a hard problem?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-modeling

Where can I propose and discuss ideas, get more mathematicians involved in discussions and propose ideas on a mathematical problem?

I have the feeling that Math StackExchange is not the right forum for it, because it seems problems have to be more concrete or specific and not a place to have more than just one discussion. For example there are places where one has to be a bit more ambiguous and vague to find new ideas to a difficult mathematical problem. I have lots of ideas, but now I don't want to open a new thread each time I get a new one after some research. (And the research I do is about a specific problem in mathematics).

*Now I just found a tag named: "mathematical modeling", can I use that for hard problems and idea and brainstorming/mingling?*

Comment: That tag is intended to be used for questions on mathematical modelling, not for "brainstorming" etc.

Comment: There's always Math Overflow.

Comment: Ok. Then I have to use Math Overflow more perhaps.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Like m.se, MathOverflow is a question/answer site, not a discussion site.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Perhaps you're right. A forum like Math Help Boards might be better suited in some respects; problem is such sites don't have a whole lot of traffic. MHB (which I help administer) has some very top-notch people, but for very hard questions like you're thinking of, if we don't have just the right person, it might not help you out much. You can always try!

Comment: @AdrianKeister Mathoverflow is probably the worst place for this. Thematical chatrooms are possible, but most of them are dead, except, maybe, homotopy one.

Comment: @xsnl: See my later post.

Comment: @AdrianKeister You have a good point: traffic is very low on such sites. I have tried them in the past. Ill take a look at MHB but else I will use this site and M.O. and take some time to select those difficult questions I have instead.

Comment: You might also want to check out any one of a number of chatrooms.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, live discussions on faculty or during conferences have no online replacement; most mathematicians I personally know have same belief. In isolation from academic society it's very unlikely that you will have possibility for such communication with positive outcome.

I do not know where you live, but if there's a university with decent math faculty nearby, I highly recommend to look for research seminars related to your theme and attend them. (They are usually semi-open to visit, communicating with seminar secretary will probably help.)